# Does word store my passwords in plaintext?

Tags: authentication, passwords, password-management

I have a document which I wrote my passwords in and saved it to my disk, and I have been hearing a lot about programs storing passwords in plaintext

Did word store my password I saved in plaintext???
If yes, how do I have a word with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Did word store my password I saved in plaintext???

The answer is in your question. "I have a document which I wrote my passwords in and saved it to my disk" is the definition of saving password in plain text.

> If yes, how do I have a word [document] with it?

You do not. That is, if you want to avoid saving passwords in plain text. Instead, you should use a password manager, such as Keepass (many others exist).

Comment: So is word not a recommanded password manager? I thought since it came from Office, it was certified for work and they have good security I think

Comment: @Discordexpert What exactly made you believe that Word was a password manager? The fact that software comes from a reputable source doesn't mean that it's suitable for all tasks. Adobe Photoshop also comes from a reputable company, but that doesn't make Photoshop a password manager either.

Comment: @MechMK1 for starters its called word, and it has a save feature. So I figured it could save words, and my passwords are words. So it manages my passwords, I even found a manage button that I am not sure what does yet

Comment: @Discordexpert Word is not a password manager. It was never intended to be used as one. What do you think "plain text" means and why it is a bad practice to write down passwords?

Comment: Its bad cause if a hacker hacks into my computer and hacks my word password manager they gain access to my passwords and can sell them on the password manaegr black market.

Comment: @discord - it's bad because you are using the wrong tool for the job. If you want to use a password manager, use one, not a word processor.

Comment: Obvious troll is obvious. Stop responding.